# What is signed integer overflow?

Tags: c, cs50

I'm learning C from CS50. When I run my code, it says 'signed integer overflow'.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x = 41;
    int c = 0;
    while(x>=25)
    {
      c = c+1;
    }

    printf("%i\n", c);
}
```

Can someone explain what that means?

Comment: You *do* know you have an infinite loop?

Comment: `c` is incremented infinitely because the while loop never ends. `x` is never decremented so always stays at 41, and 41 is always greaten than 25.

Comment: You're adding to c forever. It can only hold so high of a value.

Comment: As for the *overflow* issue. Lets say you have a `signed char`, whose range of values are `-128` to `127` (using [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)). Now if the value of a variable of type `signed char` is `127`, and you add `1`, what happens then? What is the new value? You don't know, because you have a *signed integer overflow*, which leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). The problem is the same with `int` (which is really `signed int`), the values are just larger.

Comment: just add `x = x -1;` into your while ;)

Answer (score 8):

Your while condition will always be true, meaning the loop will run forever, adding 1 to `c` in each iteration.

Since `c` is a (`signed`) `int` it means it will increment slowly to its max value, and after that the next increment would be UB (undefined behavior). What many machines will do in this specific UB is to turn `c` negative, which I guess is not what you wanted. This happens due to a phenomenon called "signed integer overflow".

Let's assume 32-bit `int` and using *two's complement*. A `signed int` will look like this in binary `sign bit (0 for positive, 1 for negative) | 31 bits`. zero will look like `000...00`, one like `000...01` and so on.

Max signed int will look like `0111...11` ([2,147,483,647](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,147,483,647)). When adding 1 to this number you'll get `100...000` which flipped the sign bit which will now result in a negative number. Adding another 1 to this will result in `100...001` which again has the sign bit on meaning it is still negative...

Declaring `c` as unsigned would ensure `c` remains non-negative. Also, making the loop end with `while(x-- >= 25)` could also be a good idea :)

Comment: The value of `c` doesn't *have* to become negative. It will most likely happen in reality, but technically it's *undefined behavior* and as such just about anything could happen.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude even under two's complement assumption? fixed it...

Comment: Yes, singed integer over- or under-flow is UB in the C specification. This has to be since it can not assume any special method to encode negative numbers. In reality though, the common two's complement encoding will make it negative on overflow.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude What you describe would be "implementation defined behaviour". Undefined behaviour means that the compiler's optimizer is allowed to assume it can never happen and rewrite your code based on that assumption. (See, for example, [this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/0ubnbS).)

Answer (score 2):

"Signed integer overflow" means that you tried to store a value that's outside the range of values that the type can represent, and the result of that operation is *undefined* (in this particular case, your program halts with an error).

Since your `while` loop never terminates (`x >= 25` evaluates to true, and you never change the value of `x`), you keep adding 1 to `c` until you reach a value outside the range that a signed `int` can represent.

Remember that in C, integral and floating-point types have fixed sizes, meaning they can only represent a fixed number of values.  For example, suppose `int` is 3 bits wide, meaning it can only store 8 distinct values.  What those values are depends on how the bit patterns are interpreted.  You could store "unsigned" (non-negative) values `[0..7]`, or "signed" (negative and non-negative) values `[-3...3]` or `[-4..3]` depending on representation.  Here are several different ways you can interpret the values of three bits:

```
Bits    Unsigned    Sign-Magnitude    1's Complement    2's Complement
----    --------    -------------     --------------    -------------- 
 000           0                0                  0                 0
 001           1                1                  1                 1
 010           2                2                  2                 2
 011           3                3                  3                 3
 100           4               -0                 -3                -4
 101           5               -1                 -2                -3
 110           6               -2                 -1                -2
 111           7               -3                 -0                -1
```

Most systems use 2's Complement for signed integer values.  Yes, sign-magnitude and 1's complement have positive and negative representations for zero.

So, let's say `c` is our 3-bit signed `int`.  We start it at `0` and add `1` each time through the loop.  Eveything's fine until `c` is `3` - using our 3-bit signed representation, we cannot represent the value `4`.  The result of the operation is *undefined behavior*, meaning the compiler is not required to handle the issue in any particular way.  Logically, you'd expect the value to "wrap around" to a negative value based on the representation in use, but even that's not necessarily true, depending on how the compiler optimizes arithmetic operations.

Note that *unsigned* integer overflow is well-defined - you'll "wrap around" back to 0.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to know what a "signed integer overflow condition" is.

It is a condition which appears when a mathematical operation results in a number which is out of bounds of the data type, which is signed integer overflow in your case.

This happens because your loop goes on infinitely, because `x >= 25` will always be true.

Answer (score 1):

An integer can only hold so many numbers before it reaches its max value. In your while loop it says to execute it while `x>=25`. Since x is 41 and x never decreases in its value that means the while loop will always execute because it's always true since `41>=25`.

An integer can only hold up to the number 2,147,483,647 which means that since C will keep on adding to itself as the while loop will always be true once it reaches 2,147,483,647 it will give you an error because an integer cannot go past that as it doesn't have enough memory to.

Answer (score 0):

Well... You have an infinite loop because your value `x` will always be bigger than 25 since you dont decrease it.
since the loop is infinite, your value `c` reaches the max size of an int (which is 2,147,483,647 if 4bytes).
You can try this in order to escape the infinite loop:

```
int main(void)
{
    int x = 41;
    int c = 0;

    while (x >= 25)
    {
      c = c+1;
      x--;
    }
    printf("%i\n", c);
}
```