# Binary to decimal conversion C code - Problem in satisfying particular test cases

Tags: c

C program to convert input binary number to decimal number

The code works fine for the input 10001000, 101100 for which the outputs are 136 and 44 respectively, but it fails for

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main() {
    int t,i,s,r;
    int b;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%d",&b);
        i=0;
        s=0;
        while(b!=0)
        {
            r=b%10;
            s=s+r*pow(2,i);
            b=b/10;
            i++;
        }
        printf("%d\n",s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

1st test cases are satisfied as follows:
For Input:
2
10001000
101100
Your Output is:
136
44
The following test case is not satisfied and error is as follows:
Error in the output:
Wrong Answer. !!!Wrong Answer
Possibly your code doesn't work correctly for multiple test-cases (TCs).
The first test case where your code failed:

Input:
11111111111

Its Correct output is:
2047

And Your Code's output is:
-3809
Can anyone please suggest me the necessary changes?

Comment: If you know the test case where your program fails, you should try running it in a debugger and step through your code watching the contents of involved variables.

Comment: Your input seems over the (typical) maximum int value.

Comment: I went through the indentation, I hope it is readable now.

Comment: The problem is that you're inputting your "binary" number as an int, which is confusing and unnecessarily limiting.  When you input 11111111111, you are *not* inputting a binary number, you are inputting a decimal number, and the decimal number 11111111111 requires 34 bits.  You should input your binary number as a *string*, not an int.

Comment: The test case(input) is given by the tester by default, and it is giving the wrong answer for my code, please suggest necessary changes.

Comment: Try reading the binary number as a string and test each character. As Steve Summit has already mentioned, the input value is too big to read into a 32 bit integer.

Comment: To make sure you really stress your program, also test it on 1111111111111111111111111111111, which (assuming you're on a 32-bit machine) should yield 2147483647.

Comment: @Steve Summit Thanks for your answer, but instead of string data type, "long int " can be used & it worked perfectly fine for all test cases. Thanks again!

Comment: qwerty9875: It only "worked perfectly" because you limited your tests. String parsing is the way to go, like @SteveSummit suggested.

Comment: On a machine with 32 bit integers you would need to input 32 decimal digits to enter numbers in valid integer range. A 32 digit number will definitely not fit into a `long int` but into a `char buf[33];`

Comment: @qwerty9875 Did it work on the test case I suggested?

Comment: @qwerty9875 There are two completely different definitions of "works perfectly fine".  Definition #1 is "works for all test cases".  But definition #2 is "works for the right reasons".  The code you've got, I'm afraid, works for the wrong reasons.  It may seem to work today (and as a learning exercise that may be all that matters), but it has fundamental flaws that would doom it in the long run and that (if I were your instructor) I would downgrade it for.

Answer (score 3):

Among several other issues with your code - you're trying to interpret the string "11111111111" (11 times '1') as an integer. However, the integer type on your machine uses 4 bytes, and the highest number it can represent is 2^31 - 1. The number 11,111,111,111 is higher than 2^33. So - you get [signed integer overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46789702/what-is-signed-integer-overflow) behavior.

Try parsing your input as a string, not as a huge number...

But - next time, please:

1. Use proper indentation.
2. Use meaningful variable names (e.g. `number_of_conversions`, not `t`).
3. Use a *minimal* example. For example, we didn't need to have the external loop over `t` - you could have demonstrated your issue with just a single conversion.
4. Check the results of your library calls! `scanf()` can fail, you know.

Answer (score 0):

when you are declaring the variable, increase the range of int by using
"unsigned long long" before int.
while using scanf function use format specifier as "%lld".

Comment: Please add some code to your question to make it more usable