# I need to print the sum of a array using function in c

Tags: c

the following is my code im not getting the correct output can anyone say what is wrong with my code?

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 

int printArrayElementsSum(int *a,int n){
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        sum+=a[i];
    }
    printf("%d",sum);
}

int main(){
    int N;
    scanf("%d",&N);
    int arr[N],index;
    for(index=0;index<N;index++){
        scanf("%d",&arr[index]);
    }
    printArrayElementsSum(arr,N);
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please no pictures of input and output, just include them in your question, easier to reproduce...

Comment: Your program has undefined behavior since you don't return an `int` from `printArrayElementsSum` and you also have **signed integer overflow** which means that your `int` can't handle numbers that big. - I  also agree with @alex01011. It's very hard to copy/paste the figures you've used in your question when you have them as pictures.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is signed integer overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46789702/what-is-signed-integer-overflow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to store the number 3000000023 in a 32 bit signed integer, which "wraps around" to yield your program's output.  You canfix this by using `long` instead of `int` for your variables (and you'll have to change the `%d` format string to `%ld`).

Comment: You also might want to change the function type to `void print..()` since you are not actually returning anything.